# CP Kafka Connect not working with cp-ksqldb-server 5.5.0

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I tried to run kafka with docker. I am able to run zookeeper, broker and kafka connect.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csU1b.png)

but when I tried to run ksqldb-server, kafka connect stopped.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qt8W.png)

here my docker-compose file :

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
      - ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME=2000
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=zookeeper:2181
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://schema-registry:8081
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.5.0
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    volumes:
      - mi4:/tmp/
    #  - $PWD/tmp:/tmp/
    environment:
      - CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=broker:29092
      - CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=localhost
      - CONNECT_REST_PORT=8083
      - CONNECT_GROUP_ID=compose-connect-group
      - CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=connect-configs
      - CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=connect-offsets
      - CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=connect-statuses
      - CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER= io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      - CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER= io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      - CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://schema-registry:8081
      - CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://schema-registry:8081
      - CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER= org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      - CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER= org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      - CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL=INFO
      - CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS= org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR
      - CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java/
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
      - schema-registry
  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:5.5.0
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    environment:
      - KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=broker:29092
      - KSQL_CONFIG_DIR=/etc/ksql
      - KSQL_HOST_NAME=ksqldb-server
      - KSQL_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8088
      - KSQL_AUTO_OFFSET_RESET=earliest
      - KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING=0
      - KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://schema-registry:8081
      - KSQL_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES= io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor
      - KSQL_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES= io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor
      - KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL=http://connect:8083
volumes:
  mi4:
```

Have you idea!!

I checked the logs of my container but there no added information for the error.

Answer (score 1):

I modified docker settings.
**

> Docker memory is allocated minimally at 8 GB. When using Docker
>   Desktop for Mac, the default Docker memory allocation is 2 GB. You can
>   change the default allocation to 8 GB in Docker.

**